# Identify a bug in pattern matcher

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

I've just got another pattern matching bug.

Google find plenty of them. And this google request should be linked first in any akka documentation to give a user fair info about hardships of message-based programming in scala.

Some of this bugs are resolved, some not. They are general and different pieces of code may be applied to one bug.

I have one piece that still cease to work in 2.9.2 and I'd like to know the bug status. So I need help from someone familiar with scala bug database who can point me to the bug that corresponds to my code.

sample code:

```
object Test {
  sealed trait Pattern[T] {
    val data : T
  }
  object Pattern {
    def apply[T](data : T) : Pattern[T] = Primary(data)
    def apply[T](data : T, f : Float) : Pattern[T] = Full(data,f)
    def unapply[T](pat : Pattern[T]) : Option[T] = Some(pat.data)
  }
  final case class Primary[T](data : T) extends Pattern[T]
  final case class Full[T](data : T, f: Float) extends Pattern[T]

  val recognize1 : PartialFunction[Pattern[Any],Unit] = {
    case pat@Pattern(d) => println("pattern recognized: " + pat)
    case _ => println("simple failed")
  }
  val recognize2 : PartialFunction[Pattern[Any],Unit] = {
    case pat@Full(x : Int, f) => println("full@Int detected: " + pat)
    case pat@Pattern(c : Float) => println("pat@Float detected: " + pat)
    case _ => println("full-pattern detection failed")
  }
  val recognize3 : PartialFunction[Pattern[Any],Unit] = {
    case pat@Pattern(x : Int) => println("pat@Int detected: " + pat)
    case pat@Pattern(c : Float) => println("pat@Float detected: " + pat)
    case _ => println("pattern-pattern detection failed")
  }
  val recognize4 : PartialFunction[Pattern[Any],Unit] = {
    case pat@Full(x : Int, f) => println("full@Int detected: " + pat)
    case pat@Full(c : Float, f) => println("full@Float detected: " + pat)
    case _ => println("full-full detection failed")
  }
  val allRecognize : List[PartialFunction[Pattern[Any],Unit]] =
    List( recognize1, recognize2, recognize3, recognize4)

  val tests : List[Any] = List(3) ++ List(5.0f)

  def testAll() = for (t <- tests) {
    println("test: " + t)
    val primary = Pattern(t)
    for (r <- allRecognize) r(primary)
    val full = Pattern(t,1.0f)
    for (r <- allRecognize) r(full)
    println("")
  }
}
```

and corresponding output:

```
scala> Test.testAll()
test: 3
pattern recognized: Primary(3)
full-pattern detection failed
pat@Int detected: Primary(3)
full-full detection failed
pattern recognized: Full(3,1.0)
full@Int detected: Full(3,1.0)
pat@Int detected: Full(3,1.0)
full@Int detected: Full(3,1.0)

test: 5.0
pattern recognized: Primary(5.0)
pat@Float detected: Primary(5.0)
pat@Float detected: Primary(5.0)
full-full detection failed
pattern recognized: Full(5.0,1.0)
full-pattern detection failed
pat@Float detected: Full(5.0,1.0)
full@Float detected: Full(5.0,1.0)
```

Testing Int works well because Int is matched first.

Problems arise with matching Float. When I use same extractor for Int and Float (either Pattern or Full) all works fine. But all goes wrong when I mix extractors and try extracting Int with Full and try Float with Pattern.

The main question: what bug is it (you really should know scala insides to figure it out)?

Lesser question: what is most elegant workaround to this?

Pattern trait was written as a pretty (and more memory efficient substition) for (U,Option[V])

Comment: Could you indicate what patterns, exactly, are failing? Your explanation is confusing, and the code convoluted enough to make it difficult to track down the (presumed) problem.

Comment: Object Test contains test samples tests and function testAll() that perfrom test run. Test run output is included in post

Comment: the problem: 
    pattern recognized: Full(5.0,1.0)
    full-pattern detection failed

Answer (score 2):

On Scala-2.10.0-M6 your code prints the following:

```
scala> testAll()
test: 3
pattern recognized: Primary(3)
full-pattern detection failed
pat@Int detected: Primary(3)
full-full detection failed
pattern recognized: Full(3,1.0)
full@Int detected: Full(3,1.0)
pat@Int detected: Full(3,1.0)
full@Int detected: Full(3,1.0)

test: 5.0
pattern recognized: Primary(5.0)
pat@Float detected: Primary(5.0)
pat@Float detected: Primary(5.0)
full-full detection failed
pattern recognized: Full(5.0,1.0)
pat@Float detected: Full(5.0,1.0)
pat@Float detected: Full(5.0,1.0)
full@Float detected: Full(5.0,1.0)
```

`Full(5.0f, 1.0f)` now matches `Pattern(c: Float)`, other tests seems to work as they should.

Answer (score 1):

Searching for bugs on pattern matcher is pretty useless right now, unless you are testing your code on 2.10.x or master. For two reasons:

- There are so many bugs in the pattern matcher, that finding the right one is very hard.
- The code on 2.10.x is entirely new, so the bugs on the old pattern matcher are just not relevant to the new pattern matcher (which fixed most, if not all, of them).

Comment: Is there any way to test 2.10 without installing it?